# how to restart windows service c#

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services

I want every to hour restart windows service by c# code. I have this method 
but when I but it in project installer or where? Can I put it in the same service I want to restart it?

```
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

    try
    {
        int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

        service.Stop();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

        // count the rest of the timeout
        int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
        timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

        service.Start();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a service that monitors another service? Or are you expecting the service in question to be shut down such that it must be manually started at regular intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by making a method inside the service like this

```
 private void StopService()
{
   using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController("ServiceName"))
   {
   try
   {
       TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80000);

        if (!(service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) || service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
        {
            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLog(ex);
    }
}
```

}

and make another service to restart it

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to the Windows scheduler.  Just put this function in a windows command program and schedule hourly launch of it.  Also, you could have a second service to accomplish the recycling of the first service.

-rwg